# Как одновременно выполнять 2 функции в питоне?

Tags: python, kivy

Мне нужно что бы персонаж не переставал двигаться, но при этом выполнялась одна из двух других функций.

```
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    self.pers.pos = (touch.x, touch.y)
    if 250 < touch.x < 270 and 250 < touch.y < 270:
       while 250 < touch.x < 270 and 250 < touch.y < 270: # tower 1 mid
          if our_hp != 0:
              our_hp = our_hp - 100
              sleep(2)
          elif our_hp == 0:
              print('Wait')
              sleep(2)
              print('go')
              our_hp = 1000
              self.pers.pos = (100, 100)
    if (250 < touch.x or touch.x > 270) and (250 < touch.y or touch.y > 270):
        while 250 < touch.x < 270 and 250 < touch.y < 270: # tower 1 mid
            if our_hp != 0:
                our_hp = our_hp - 100
                sleep(2)
            elif our_hp == 0:
                print('Wait')
                sleep(2)
                print('go')
                our_hp = 1000
                self.pers.pos = (100, 100)
```

Изначально our_hp = 1000
Заранее спасибо

Comment: threading.Thread

Comment: [Game Loop](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) обычно используют в игрушках